# AS3 LoaderUI if load fails load different file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-cs5

I have a UILoader (loader) on stage inside a movie clip (logoOneLoader) that I'd like to have load an image, and if that image doesn't exist, load a different image that I know does exist.  The following code loads a first image that doesn't exist, fails, catches the error, but then does not proceed to load the second image.  Any suggestions?

```
logoOneLoader = new logoLoaderGraphic();
item.addChild(logoOneLoader);
logoURL = new URLRequest("http://www.myurl.com/img/badImage.png");
logoOneLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, noLogo);
logoOneLoader.loader.load(logoURL);


function noLogo(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
event.currentTarget.close();
var logoString:String = "http://www.myurl.com/img/goodImage.png";
event.currentTarget.load(new URLRequest(logoString));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you may need to create a new loader object as well. Try this:

```
var logoOneLoader:LogoLoaderGraphic;

loadLogo("http://www.myurl.com/img/badImage.png");

function loadLogo(url:String, fallback:Boolean = true):void {
  logoOneLoader = new logoLoaderGraphic();
  item.addChild(logoOneLoader);
  logoURL = new URLRequest(url);
  if(fallback) {
      logoOneLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, noLogo);
  } else {
      logoOneLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, logoFault);
  }
  logoOneLoader.loader.load(logoURL);
}


function noLogo(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
  logoFault(event);

  var logoString:String = "http://www.myurl.com/img/goodImage.png";

  loadLogo(logoString, false);
}

function logoFault(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
   event.target.close();
  event.target.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee);
}
```

Comment: It's also probably worth nothing that while you know the image will be there the second time around the server sill may not be responding for whatever reason. It would be a good idea to make a limiter on how many times it can go and check.

Comment: Thanks for this response.  I will check your suggestion as soon as I get back to my computer in the morning.  This has been driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

You can just load the image that surely exists in a separate Loader, then in an error handler you return its clone instead of a loaded image.

```
class ExtraLoader extends Sprite {
    private var loader:Loader; 
    private static var defaultImage:Bitmap; // load it beforehand
    public var contents:Bitmap;
    ...
    public function loadFromURL(url:URL):void {
        loader=new Loader();
        var ur:URLRequest=new URLRequest(url);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,oops);
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,done);
        loader.load(ur);
    }
    private function oops(e:Event):void {
        loader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,oops);
        loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,done);
        contents=new Bitmap(defaultImage.bitmapData); // add "good" image
        addChild(contents);
    }
    private function done(e:Event):void {
        loader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,oops);
        loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,done);
        contents=loader.content;
        addChild(contents); // loaded image - cool, add it
    }
}
```